# How to understand the comment in 'mm/usercopy.c'

Tags: linux-kernel

How to understand the following comment in the `mm/usercopy.c` source file of the Linux kernel?

> This implements the various checks for CONFIG_HARDENED_USERCOPY*, which are designed to **protect kernel memory from needless exposure
>   and overwrite** under many unintended conditions.

I want to know the exact meaning of "memory exposure" and "memory overwrite".

[Screenshot with the comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvuGU.png)

Comment: Proper relative path of the file in the question is `mm/usercopy.c`. Exactly this file one should search after cloning the Linux kernel repo. Prefix `linux/` corresponds to the repository name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONFIG_HARDENED_USERCOPY` option tries to ensure that address ranges used to copy data to and from user space are valid.

Taken [from LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/695991/):

> The main problems that can result from an errant user-space copy are
>   either that too much data is copied to user space, resulting in
>   leaking the contents of kernel memory, or that too much data is copied
>   from user space, which can overwrite kernel memory. If an attacker can
>   influence the allocation of objects on the kernel's heap and then
>   overwrite some of those objects, they may be able to escalate
>   privileges, run arbitrary code, or crash the kernel. Information leaks
>   are generally less dangerous, but the kernel does have critical data
>   (e.g. keys) that could be exposed. Beyond that, determining the layout
>   of kernel memory by way of an information leak can also provide
>   information needed to exploit other kernel flaws.